# Segfault in simple C/NASM x86_64/C program printing float

Tags: c, linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

1. In my C code I call assembly (NASM x86_64) function (main.c).
2. In assembly I call C function (printf.asm)
3. That function prints float using printf. (c_printf.c)
4. I'm getting segfault.

Should I compile/link in another way? Maybe the way I call C function from assembly is incorrect?

I compile with:

```
gcc -c c_printf.c
nasm -f elf64 -F dwarf -g printf.asm
gcc -o main printf.o c_printf.o main.c
```

My code:

main.c

```
extern void start_asm(void);
int main(void) {
    start_asm();
    return 0;
}
```

printf.asm

```
global start_asm
extern printf_float
start_asm:
    call printf_float
    ret
```

c_printf.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printf_float(void) {
    printf("%f\n", 42.0f);
}
```

Maybe valgrind output will be helpful?

```
==16257== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16257== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16257== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16257== Command: ./main
==16257== 
--16257-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--16257-- When reading debug info from /home/starsep/stack/main:
--16257-- Overrun whilst parsing .debug_abbrev section(2)
==16257== 
==16257== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==16257==  General Protection Fault
==16257==    at 0x4E8F824: printf (printf.c:28)
==16257==    by 0x40055F: printf_float (in /home/starsep/stack/main)
==16257==    by 0x400534: ??? (printf.asm:6)
==16257==    by 0x4E5A82F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==16257== 
==16257== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16257==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16257==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==16257== 
==16257== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16257== 
==16257== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16257== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[1]    16257 segmentation fault  valgrind ./main
```

Comment: You messed up stack alignment. Instead of `call printf_float; ret` do `jmp printf_float`.

Comment: I'd like to return to assembly from C function. Example: I'd like to call printf_float twice.

Comment: Then maintain stack alignment by hand. E.g. `sub rsp, 8; call printf_float; add rsp, 8; ret` Note that `call` changes rsp by 8, and the ABI requires 16 byte alignment, hence the additional 8 needed.

Comment: Thank you! I was sure that stack alignment is 8 bytes, not 16. That explains a lot.

Comment: 16 bytes so it's easier to use aligned SSE instructions. Same in 32 bit mode nowadays too.

Comment: That's interesting, many SO posts show that `printf` works even if you violate the ABI alignment requirements.  But those were all with no FP params (only integer or no params).  It's a bit surprising that it does any 16B loads/stores while printing a scalar float, but maybe that happens while handling var-args.  Even if it was vectorized, I'd be surprised if it spilled any vectors to the stack.

Comment: BTW, it's easier to use `gdb` to track down segfaults, since you can see what instruction faulted.  (and can inspect register contents)  See the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for tips.